# html onclick keeps redirecting to a function of javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, redirect

Im calling a function from onclick of a button. When i press the button it executes my function deletes everything from the screen and displays the button inside my function. Everything works ok but why does it delete everything from screen. How to make it for it to only run the function but keep previous html elements prior to clicking the function?

```
 <div id="form-container">
    <form id="dim_form" action="">
        <div class="bg">
            <label class="form-label-a" for="dimm">Dimension</label>
            <input id="dimm" type="text" />
        </div>
        <div class="bg">
            <label class="form-label-b" for="dimm_upper">Upper tolerance</label>
            <input id="dimm_upper" type="text" required />
        </div>
        <div class="bg">
            <label class="form-label-c" for="dimm_lower">Lower tolerence</label>
            <input id="dimm_lower" type="text" required />
        </div>
        <div class="bg">
            <input class="form-button" type="submit" onclick="data_table();" value="Calculate" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

data_table()

```
document.write("<input class='download' type='button' id='button-a' value='download xls' />");
```

I tried with "button" instead of submit. return false, basically everything i found on google and nothing works for me.

Comment: `document.write` will erase everything you had. Instead use `append`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`document.write` will erase everything you had earlier. Instead use `append`.

```js
function data_table() {
  const input = document.createElement('input');
  input.type = "submit";
  input.id = "button-a";
  input.value = "download xls";
  document.querySelector('.bg').appendChild(input);
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <input class="form-button" type="submit" onclick="data_table();" value="Calculate" />
</div>
```

Comment: why downvote? Initially I posted wrong code which is corrected now. Any other reason for downvote?

Comment: If form is empty it creates that button and lets me download. But if i fill the form it just refreshes and download button flashes for 0.1s.

Comment: @EvaldasBlauzdziunas - `this creates an input field than flashes for 1second and disappears`? It does not disappear, please run the code.

Comment: OK thank you i got it to work using onsubmit="return false" in form.

Answer (score 0):

The `write()` method is mostly used for testing: If it is used after an HTML document is fully loaded, it will delete all existing HTML.

When this method is not used for testing, it is often used to write some text to an output stream opened by the `document.open()` method. See "More Examples" below

see the full documentation here: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_write.asp

if you want to add some nodes without cleaning the whole HTML try `append`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append

Answer (score -1):

Document is referred to the entire html page when you are trying to do document.write it will write on the entire page.... 
There can be couple of work arounds but i will suggest this one

1. Give class to the element you want to add element to.
2. Get element by the class you assign to the element in first step

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("example");
```

3. if you want to keep whats already there

```
x.appendChild("whatever you want to add goes here");
```

4. if you want to add only new element and discard everything previously present

```
x.innerHtml="whatever you want to add goes here";
```